# If any matches any in list using Entity Famework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have this piece of code:

```
var files = (from f in _fileRep.GetFiles()
              where fileID.Contains(f.FileID)
              select f.FileName).ToList();

var destFiles = (from f in _fileRep.GetFiles()
                    where f.FolderID == destFolderID 
                     select f.FileName).ToList();

bool valid = destFiles.Any(x => files.Contains(x));
```

fileID is int[], and I'm trying to validate if a list of filenames exists where FolderID matches destFolderID when moving files in a database.

I'm getting:

```
"Unable to create a null constant value of type 'System.Int32[]'. 
Only entity types, enumeration types or primitive types are 
supported in this context."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that perhaps `fileID` is null. You can easily convert it to an empty array if it is null using the `??` operator. Also, unless you really need to access items by index, `.ToList` probably isn't necessary.

You could try this:

```
fileID = fileID ?? new int[0];
var files = _fileRep.GetFiles().Where(f => fileID.Contains(f.FileID));
var destFiles = _fileRep.GetFiles().Where(f => f.FolderID == destFolderID);
bool valid = files.Join(destFiles, f => f.FileName, f => f.FileName).Any();
```

Or even this:

```
fileID = fileID ?? new int[0];
bool valid = 
    (from f in _fileRep.GetFiles()
     join g in _fileRep.GetFiles() on f.FileName equals g.FileName
     where fileID.Contains(f.FileID) && g.FolderID == destFolderID
     select f).Any();
```